# After Moving Site from One server to another getting errors with custom webparts

Tags: web-part

Getting following error message after moving a site from one server to another server using Backup and Restore Commands:

Could not load file or assembly 'XXXXXXXXX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f07b43252e63d943' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 97a616ce-de6c-444e-9a72-55beb3a5ec65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean from one SharePoint Farm to another?

Then you need to deploy the custom web part (WSP) to the new farm. Solutions are not included in Backup/Restore of a site collection.